# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=/* }

Tags: java, android

Please help me. I am an absolute beginner. Can't find videos on it. Debugging the code is giving faults mentioned below. Can't understand the meaning of those. Please help with the correct code

app that tries to open file browser but I am getting debugging messages at

```
com.example.anirbitadak.translator.MainActivity.startsearch(MainActivity.java:59)
  at com.example.anirbitadak.translator.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:15)
  at com.example.anirbitadak.translator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)*/
```

Activity:

```
package com.example.anirbitadak.translator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button upload, translate;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    translate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.translate);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
           startsearch();

        }
    });
  }

private void startsearch() {//declaration of startsearch();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("/*.docx");
    //intent.setType("/*.pdf");
    //intent.setType("/*.doc");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, data);

    if (requestcode == REQUEST_CODE && resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
           //Flashing the path
            Toast.makeText(this, "Uri:" + uri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Path:" + uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message? It seems that it may be incomplete. It'll be helpful for others if you post the entire exception and not just where it occurred. Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157490/android-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-error-how-it-will-resolve or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514414/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-when-the-manifest-is-correct.  Did you try googling the error message?  If you did read the related posts, explain why those don't apply to your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: No Activity found to handle Intent error? How it will resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157490/android-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-error-how-it-will-resolve)

Comment: I tried all but couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good to me.

Are you sure there's a `DocumentsProvider` installed on the device that can handle .docx?

Are you sure your mime pattern is correct? The mime for docx is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. Regardless, it seems incorrect you are specifying it as starting with a "/", as mime types are slash separated but do not begin with an "/".

Comment: yeah device has a DocumentsProvider.